# Can't open file in folder. path is not correct

Tags: c++, path, ifstream, dirent.h

I'm having a problem to open my file, and hence when I try to read it using geline a get an empty string.

I have a folder with several text files, and I want to read all of them. my code is in folder C:\root\pjt and my files are in folder C:\root\files.
I try to read the files using dirent.h library, I used getline with no success, but than I realized it couldn't even open the file, so I just tried opening the file, but that didn't work either.

```
void listFile() {                                                               
    DIR *pDIR;                                                                  
    struct dirent *entry;                                                       
    string line;                                                                

    if (pDIR = opendir("../../../files")) {                                     
        while (entry = readdir(pDIR)) {                                         
            string filename(entry->d_name);                                     
            ifstream infile(filename);                                          
            infile.open(filename);                                              
            //I need the files with "records" in their name                     
            if (filename.find("records") != string::npos) {                     
                //infile.open(filename);                                        
                //while (!infile.eof()) {                                       
                //infile.get(buffer, '\r\n');                                   
                //getline(infile, line);                                        
                //}                                                             
                //infile.close();                                               
                infile.open(filename);                                          
                //IT NEVER GETS TO OPEN THE FILE!!!                             
                if (infile.is_open()) {                                         
                    while (getline(infile, line))                               
                    {                                                           
                        cout << line << '\n';                                   
                    }                                                           
                    infile.close();                                             
                } else cout << "Unable to open file";                           
            }                                                                   
        }                                                                       
        closedir(pDIR);                                                         
    }                                                                           
}
```

I want to be able to read the file, I suspect I can't do it because the path is wrong.
Thanks for the help

Comment: File paths are not relative to where your code is.

Comment: The trick is to **write** a file using the path you are interested in. Then see where that file appears. That will tell you which folder the path refers to. If the file doesn't appear then the folder doesn't exist, in which case just try to write a file with just a filename, and see where that appears.

Comment: The `getwd` function is also helpful, if supported by your system.

Comment: What's not working, `opendir`, `readdir` or `infile.open`?  Running the program under a debugger will tell you, and as user4581301 says, seeing what `getcwd` returns will help.